# Installing more RAM on laptop than specified, OK?

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a 2019 HP Pavilion laptop in which 16GB of RAM are specified (as a maximum, I guess). However, when I ran "sudo dmidecode -t memory | grep -i max" on the terminal, it output:

```
Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
   Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
   Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
```

If 32GB RAM were installed would it be utilized by the laptop?

Comment: Usually when selecting a RAM upgrade I check the CPU spec sheet (e.g. [i5-8300H](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134876/intel-core-i5-8300h-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html)). For example, according to the spec sheet in "memory specifications" the theoretically computer could handle 64 GB split over 2 Memory Channels. Given that the laptop was built to have 2 RAM slots you would be good to go from here. If you post your exact computer model number and processor I can give you a more direct answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible things that may happen: Either the boot will fail or you will use only capacity given by the hardware. Sometimes real capacity they give you as supported is not the real capacity the hardware can handle but it is highly experimental on your end, I would recommend if possible check on the store before buying if they allow you that, some stores allows that in here. I actually had this issue before I installed more ram but I could only use half of it, but it worked for years,

Answer (score 0):

I think if you install more RAM, you should be OK, as long as you stay under 32GB.